# Can Z values be used to determine relative importance of variables in a logistic regression model?

Tags: regression, logistic, logit

So in this example:
http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/output/stata_logistic.htm

Is "read" the most important variable to the model?

Answer (score 3):

No. "z values" are the ratio of the coefficient estimate divided by the standard error of the estimator (easily verifiable in the link).

As such, they provide an indication as to how much uncertainty "surrounds" the point estimate of the coefficient. The larger the "z value" gets, the less uncertainty there is, since it means that the standard error gets smaller and smaller *relative* to the coefficient value. So a confidence interval around the point estimate will be tighter.

Moreover, in logistic regression, the point estimates do not reflect the "partial marginal effect" of each regressor on the dependent variable, as in linear regression. Here regressors affect the probabilities around the dependent variable, and also, due to the non-linear structure, the effect of the one is not immediately separable from the effect of the others. So it is a tad more elaborate (compared to linear regression) to accurately assess the contribution of each regressor to the probabilities related to the dependent variable.

Comment: Thank you for the well-written response. Are there any generally accepted methods for determining relative variable importance in logistic regression?

Comment: That is too open a question, since logistic regression has become almost equally widely applied as linear regression in the last decades (or more, maybe). And there are many variants of logistic regression, not just one. You will have to dive into the literature. There are numerous resources available over the web, where you can find material regarding the interpretation-assessment of the results of logistic regression, starting perhaps with this site.